# Sending Email from SharePoint via PowerShell - Mysterious Question Marks

Tags: html, css, powershell, sharepoint, outlook

I have been searching all day for an answer to this. My PowerShell script reads from a SharePoint list, creates an HTML email, then sends it to everyone in the company.

For some reason, when I insert images, the images appear in the emails, but they always have a random question mark before or after the image. It is not the question mark in the black diamond that people talk about. It's using UTF-8. I've also tried Western European (ISO) and it still shows.

Here is an example of the line before I send the email, written to the host in PowerShell:

`<img src="LINK" alt="ALT.png" style="margin:5px;width:382px;height:243px;" width = "300" >​<br></p></div></div></div></BODY>`

and then when I view the source in Outlook after it's sent:

`<img src="LINK" alt="ALT.png" style="margin:5px;width:382px;height:243px;" width="300">?<br></p></div></div></div></body></html>`

Boom, random question mark at the end of the img tag. I've tried to do a replace: 
`$emailtext = $emailtext.Replace("><", " " >")`

Didn't work.

One more example of before sent with a different image:

`<p style="text-align:center;">​<img src="LINK" alt="ALT.jpg" style="margin:5px;width:253px;height:111px;" width = "300" >`

And after:

`<p style="text-align:center;">?<img src="LINK" alt="ALT.jpg" style="margin:5px;width:253px;height:111px;" width="300">`

Again, boom, random question mark. This time before the img tag.

Please help. I need to roll out these emails very soon and this would be a little embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is the problem but make sure you end your image tag <img src='' />, Also it could be the server side scripting you use to generate this template.

Comment: Post your code? "It's using UTF-8" - what is? Sounds like there's a dozen moving parts to this system, which one "is using UTF-8", are you sure *all* of them are? Random question marks are just .. basically *always* encoding problems, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Soo, not sure why, but this is only a problem when the images are being posted from the Site Assets library. There's no random question mark when they're coming from the Publishing Images library. I guess I will mark as answered and leave up in case anyone finds this helpful. Thanks for the replies I got!